# Custom Glossary Fonts

Tags: fonts, lyx, glossaries

I'm using LyX, and have the fonts all set as the same (because of language considerations) in the `Document > Settings... > Fonts` section. This shows up like so in the Glossary section:

[image: Problematic Glossary Font Settings]

If I set the sans serif font in `Document > Settings... > Fonts` to something different, it can show up like this:

[image: Better Glossary Font Settings]

This is visually preferable, but because I need to have the other font to display the non-English text in the rest of my document, I can't make the change this way.

Is there a command to change the font of the Glossary section label and entry labels, *specifically* -- without having it affect the rest of my document? I've tried a bunch of commands based on results I've found online, but none of them provided any useful results.

Note: I cannot simply set the text to 'bold' because the font that I need to use for my document does not have a prominent 'bold' setting -- meaning that it looks very much the same even when set to 'bold'.